# Spark SQL - getting row count for each window using spark SQL window functions

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to use spark SQL window functions to do some aggregations and windowing.

Suppose I'm using the example table provided here a: https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html

[image]

I want to run the query to give me the max 2 revenue for each category and also **the count of product for each category**.

After I run this query

```
SELECT
  product,
  category,
  revenue
FROM (
  SELECT
    product,
    category,
    revenue,
    dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY revenue DESC) as rank
    count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY revenue DESC) as count
  FROM productRevenue) tmp
WHERE
  rank <= 2
```

I got the table like this:

```
product category    revenue count
pro2    tablet  6500    1
mini    tablet  5500    2
```

instead of

```
product category    revenue count
pro2    tablet  6500    5
mini    tablet  5500    5
```

which is what I expected.

How should I write my code to get the right count for each category (instead of using another separate **Group By** statement)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Spark` if **window** clause having **order by** window defaults to `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`.

For your case add **`ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING`** in count(*) window clause.

**`Try with:`**

```
 SELECT
  product,
  category,
  revenue,count
FROM (
  SELECT
    product,
    category,
    revenue,
    dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY revenue DESC) as rank,
    count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY revenue DESC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) as count
  FROM productRevenue) tmp
WHERE
  rank <= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY revenue DESC) as count` to `count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY category DESC) as count`. You will get expected result.

Try below code.

```
scala> spark.sql("""SELECT
     |   product,
     |   category,
     |   revenue,
     |   rank,
     |   count
     | FROM (
     |   SELECT
     |     product,
     |     category,
     |     revenue,
     |     dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY revenue DESC) as rank,
     |     count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY category DESC) as count
     |   FROM productRevenue) tmp
     | WHERE
     |   tmp.rank <= 2 """).show(false)

+----------+----------+-------+----+-----+
|product   |category  |revenue|rank|count|
+----------+----------+-------+----+-----+
|Pro2      |tablet    |6500   |1   |5    |
|Mini      |tablet    |5500   |2   |5    |
|Thin      |cell phone|6000   |1   |5    |
|Very thin |cell phone|6000   |1   |5    |
|Ultra thin|cell phone|5000   |2   |5    |
+----------+----------+-------+----+-----+
```